Prove $\varphi : k^n \to \text{Spec}(K[x_1, \cdots, x_n])$ $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \mapsto (x_1-a_1, \cdots, x_n-a_n)$ is continuous
This is Exercise 6.70 from Rotman, Advanced modern algebra. The question is:

Let $K$ be uncountable and algebraically closed field. $K^n$ and $\text{Spec}(K[x_1, \cdots, x_n])$ are equipped with Zariski topology. Prove $\begin{align*} \varphi : K^n &\to \text{Spec}(K[x_1, \cdots, x_n]) \\ (a_1, \cdots, a_n) &\mapsto (x_1-a_1, \cdots, x_n-a_n) \end{align*}$ is continuous.

My attempt:
The Zariski topology on $k^n$ is defined by closed sets which are $\text{Var}(I)$ where $I \subseteq K[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$. The Zariski topology on $\text{Spec}(K[x_1, \cdots,x_n])$ is defined by closed sets which has form $\bar{I} = \left\{ P \mid I \subseteq P \subseteq K[x_1, \cdots, x_n] \right\}$.
Since we want to show $\varphi$ is continuous, we need to pick any arbitrary closed set in $\text{Spec}(K[x_1, \cdots, x_n])$, and show that the preimage is closed.
Since $\text{Im}\varphi$ is a set of some maximal ideal in $K[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$, we only need to show that preimage of $\text{Im}\varphi \cap \bar{I}$ is closed.
I want to show that there are only finitely many maximal ideal in $\bar{I}$, so that $\text{Im}\varphi \cap \bar{I}$ are only finitely many points of $\varphi(\alpha_i)$. Then the preimage is finite union of closed points $\bigcup \alpha_i$ which is closed.
But I don't know how to show $\bar{I}$ contains only finitely many maximal ideal. Is it possible to contain infinitely many of maximal ideal?
Thank you

Your approach cannot work in general - consider the whole space when $n>0$. How much do you know about the Zariski topology?

@KReiser I only the definition of Zariski topology on k^n and Spec(R). I know a little property of affine varieties. Could this question be answered in a simple way?

Of course, it can be answered in a simple way. Why don't you start by writing down the definition for the Zariski topology on each object in your post with an [edit]?

@KReiser I wrote down the definition and took a second thought but nothing came up. Could you give more hint?

@KReiser Is it like this: $\text{Var}(M) \subseteq \text{Var}(I) \iff \sqrt{I} \subseteq M$. Thus, $\forall \alpha \in \text{Var}(I) =  \text{Var}(\sqrt{I}), \exists \varphi(\alpha) = M$ s.t. $\sqrt{I} \subseteq M$. Therefore, the $\varphi^{-1}(\bar{I}) = \text{Var}(I)$ which is closed in $K^n$

This is an immediate consequence of the definitions and the observation
$$f \in (x_1-a_1,\dotsc,x_n-a_n) \iff f(a)=0$$
If $I \subseteq K[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is an ideal, then
$$\varphi^{-1}(V(I)) = \{a \in K^n : I \subseteq (x_1-a_1,\dotsc,x_n-a_n)\} = \{a \in K^n : \forall f \in I ~ (f(a) = 0)\} = V(I)$$
is closed in $K^n$ by the definition of the Zariski topology.
